# Shanty-Mongo and Zend_Paginator

Tags: zend-framework, mongodb

Does anybody know how I can integrate the Shanty-Mongo adapter with Zend Pagination?

https://github.com/coen-hyde/Shanty-Mongo

This is the snippet I found on the following page but have no idea what the $cursor variable references:

```
$adapter = new Shanty_Paginator_Adapter_Mongo(Shanty_Mongo_Iterator_Cursor $cursor);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
```

https://github.com/coen-hyde/Shanty-Mongo/pull/18

Answer (score 1):

Fount the solution.  Here's an example of my query...

```
        $cursor = Model_Mongo_Locations::all();

        $adapter = new Shanty_Paginator_Adapter_Mongo($cursor);
        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);

        $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
        $page = $filter->filter($page);

        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(6);
        $paginator->setPageRange(5);
```

Comment: Can you please tell why do you add limit(24) on the first line?

Comment: Don't you need to use both limit and skip on the first line?

Comment: That actually doesnt belong there for the general use case.  However my intention was to limit the total number of items fed into the paginator which didnt actually work.  I'll edit my answer.